# Why does Ionic contacts.find freezes my app?

Tags: ionic-framework, contacts

I have googled and tried to follow the solutions posted but did not come to a solution.

Does anyone have an idea why

```
 this.contacts.find(["name", "phoneNumbers"],
    {multiple: true, hasPhoneNumber: true}).then(
      (contacts) =>
      {
        this.contactList = contacts;


      }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log('contacts error');
      console.log(err);
    });
```

is freezing my whole app? While the `contacts` are grabbed the gui does not respond anymore.

**I am using : -**

```
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';
```

but I could not solve the problem. I have about **2500 contacts on my iPhone**. When using the code on `simulator` it is fine but `simulator` only has 6 contacts.

`Log` says '`Fetching in bulk 250 contacts!`' plenty of time.

I'm really stuck and would be very happy if someone could give me a hint to solve this problem.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

This plugins requires the following usage description:

*NSContactsUsageDescription* describes the reason that the app accesses the user's contacts.

To add this entry into the info.plist, you can use the edit-config tag in the config.xml like this:

```
<edit-config target="NSContactsUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need contacts access to search friends</string>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: It‘s not config issue as with 6 contacts it works fine

Comment: Does no one have a solution for that?

Comment: Try to use this cordova plugin: https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers

Comment: Hello parrycima. I've tried, but navigator.contactsPhoneNumbers.list returns null and I could find a solution for that. Do you have a link to a working example? I'm really stuck at this point......

Comment: Hello - FINALLY!!!! Fixed it according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647425/getting-count-of-contacts-correct-but-getting-null-values-for-contacts-in-ionic

Answer (score -1):

Try to read only the data do you need. In desiredFields you can specify this camps. For example: Obtain only "name" and "phoneNumbers" of all information about each contact.

```
this.contacts.find(["name", "phoneNumbers"],
{multiple: true, hasPhoneNumber: true}, desiredFields: ['name','phoneNumbers']).then(
  (contacts) =>
  {
    this.contactList = contacts;


  }
).catch(err => {
  console.log('contacts error');
  console.log(err);
});
```